# InternetGetCookie error 259 ERROR_NO_MORE_ITMES c++

Tags: c++, http, cookies, mfc

I've to check/get cookies of one site because i cannot, i've always got error 259 ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS with InternetGetCookies function

(exemple: check/get cookie of "http://www.google.fr" url doesn't run, i have Error 259.

```
wchar_t wchCookiesData[4096]; 
unsigned long ulCookiesDataLength = 0; 
bool bRet = InternetGetCookie(L"http://www.google.fr", NULL, out_pwchCookiesData, &ulCookiesDataLength );
```

That is my code just for my first test, and InternetGetCookie function return false (getlasterror() return 259)

Where InterentGetCookie get cookies??? i think is in `"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows"`, but here i don't have Cookies folder. I can see some cookies in  `"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies"`

Anyone has solution??

Thanks

Comment: It is better if you post more code lines, what really are you doing in the code.

Comment: `wchar_t wchCookiesData[4096];
unsigned long ulCookiesDataLength = 0;
bool bRet = InternetGetCookie(L"http://www.google.fr", NULL, out_pwchCookiesData, out_ulCookiesDataLength);`

That is my code just for my first test, and InternetGetCookie function return false (getlasterror() return 259)

Comment: @YannaY Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Don't change code when posting it. The code you posted in the comment above is **not** your code. It doesn't compile.

Comment: yes excuse me, i change it in my question (@IInspectable)

Comment: For mor info about API InternetGetCookie https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384710(v=vs.85).aspx, this retrieve cookies already saved for this url in your system. is this your case? if so when it was saved in your system?

Comment: So before InternetGetCookie, i have to use InternetSetCookie??? I don't understand, when i connect me on google or another web site, cookies are saved in my system???? and i can get it with InternetGetCookie

Comment: The code in your question doesn't compile. **Don't change code when copying it into your question.** Excessive use of punctuation marks doesn't help much in making a point either.

Comment: This function is explained pretty well in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384710%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I would start with making sure that you actually have any scriptable cookies from that site.

Comment: I don't understand :-/.
I develop that in iOS, it runs well. But in Windows, i cannot get cookies.
My first problem was the Wininet librairy for InternetGetGookie because i already use WinHttp librairy for my connexion with specific server after. 
I would like to connect me to a site like "www.google.com", and when i've this web page, get cookies from this web page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've just understood my problem,

You can get cookie from http connection, but no from https connection

Anyone knows how can i get cookie from https connection (my program is in C++ language)

Thanks